# Complete spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was wondering whether there are other complete spaces than R. I understand that Q are not complete since there are irrational points missing, and one can construct a Cauchy sequence of rationals that converges to irrationals. I assume the irrationals are also not complete for the same reason.

Comment: There are many complete spaces - the most "common" are the Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$. Also try to prove that $C[0,1]$ is complete with respect to the supremum norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the metric. The irrationals with the usual metric are not complete, but there is a complete metric on them that generates the same topology as the usual metric. Every compact metric space is complete in every compatible metric. Every non-compact metric space has a metric that is not complete but does generate the same topology.

Answer (score 1):

Considering only the usual metrics, the space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of $n$-tuples of the form $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is complete for any $n$.  Along those lines, you can say the same about $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Also, remember that any closed subspace of a (Hausdorf) complete space is complete as well.

For some more exotic examples, you can look at the space of functions from $[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ under different topologies.  If you take topology derived from the "supremum norm" given by $\|f\|_\infty = \sup\{|f(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}$, this is a complete space.

Answer (score 1):

Real and Complex Analysis by Walter Rudin has some neat chapters you may like to read on Banach, Hilbert and Lp spaces.